# how to display mathematical symbols in my html page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, mathjax

Hi i am using Rails, Ckeditor. In ckeditor mathematical symbols like summation, pi, are displaying properly. I am saving them to database. While displaying them, proper format is not displaying.

I need some solution. Thank you.

In editor it viewed like this:

```
x=−b±√2a  ​
```

But i got this format when it saved.

```
\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{2a}\)
```

I need to display in below format in html page.

```
 x=−b±√2a  ​
```

Solution is:

```
<head>
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['\\(','\\)']]}});
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
    \(x = -b \pm \sqrt{2a}\)
 </body>
```

Comment: A Quick Google Search Yields: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathsymbols.htm

Comment: you can use jsmath..  see example on this page http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/examples/Henrici.html

Comment: I solved it. Thanks every body for your feedback.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look like Ckeditor is saving mathematical symbols in [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). You can use [mathjax-rails](https://github.com/pmq20/mathjax-rails) to render LaTeX for the web.

A barebones usage of Mathjax would be this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['\\(','\\)']]}});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    \(x = -b \pm \sqrt{2a}\)
  </body>
</html>
```

See [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mtcUtrhD5qkglfR6aGwd?p=preview) to view the output.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers).

Answer (score 0):

Just Use:

```
document.write("x=-b&plusmn;&radic;2a");
```

or

```
div.innerHTML="x=-b&plusmn;&radic;2a";
```

Working: 

## `Fiddle`

`&plusmn;` is unicode symbol for:`±` and `&radic;` is for `√`.

Hope it'll help you.

References:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathsymbols.htm